# Neural network parameter matrix

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, neural-network

I'm trying to understand a Neural network result performed with Mathematica program.
The input code is:

```
n0 = InitializeFeedForwardNet[trainingI, trainingO, {3}, 
RandomInitialization -> LinearParameters];
{net0, rec0} = 
NeuralFit[n0, trainingI, trainingO, validationI, validationO, 
100, Separable -> False];
```

The nonlinear activation function is the standard sigmoid and I use, for example, only 3 neurons with one hidden layer. The iterations are 100.
I've one 4 input parameters and 1 output.

At the end of sumulation I've the results with some parameters and the sigmod with this form:

```
 {1.29824 + 0.0201608/(
 1 + E^(41.5202 + 8.53912 a - 19.4146 b - 1.00377 c - 67.2129 d)) - 
 0.408969/(
 1 + E^(8.99431 + 0.410461 a - 3.33504 b - 10.315 c + 1.35067 d)) - 
 0.914128/(
 1 + E^(0.950869 + 4.7525 a - 5.38699 b - 8.17521 c + 1.95281 d))}
```

Could I conclude that the matrix weight of hidden layer is

```
{{-4.7525, -0.410461, -8.53912}, {5.38699, 3.33504, 
 19.4146}, {8.17521, 10.315, 1.00377}, {-1.95281, -1.35067, 
 67.2129}, {-0.950869, -8.99431, -41.5202}}
```

the bias vector is

```
{{-0.914128}, {-0.408969}, {0.0201608}, {1.29824}}
```

and I've no output layers?
Thanks a lot and sorry if mine is a silly question!

Comment: its not like your last hidden laye is considered as output? And why not use LogSigmoid? And your code is unclear, unreadable i am doing neural networks often but only with raw coding and my own classes and libraries.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/applications/neuralnetworks/TrainingFeedforwardAndRadialBasisFunctionNetworks/7.1.0.html